# Best match for multiple values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Find the best match from multiple values and columns in MySQL.

Database:

```
id  star   point    price    
1   12     15       16
2   9      15       16
3   18     10       12
```

Find closes to this

```
star  point  price
10    15     14
```

Results

```
id: 2
```

Comment: a) what have you tried so far? b) what does "best match" mean exactly? is, e.g., the star column more important than price?

Comment: I have only tried with 1 value. But am lost now when I need to check best match for multi values. Don't know if one should be more important then other. Need to think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a distance metric.  But if you have one then you can just use `order by` and `limit`.  So, if you use a Euclidean metric:

```
select t.*
from t
order by pow(star - 10, 2) + pow(point - 15, 2) + pow(price - 14, 2)
limit 1;
```

Note:  The square root is not needed for ordering by the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Sweet! Will this also find the closes number if the number is higher then the best match?

Comment: @user2673664 . . . Yes.  You haven't specified the rules that want want for similarity and the Euclidean metric is just based on the difference between the values.